# ComboBox Isn't Being Populated with MySQL Query Result - How do I resolve it?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I trust you're all well.  I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.  My intent with the code below is the query my MySQL database and display one column of the table inside a ComboBox.  Then, when that value in the ComboBox is selected, I want all the records associated to be populated into other controls on my form (I'll create a separate question for this part).

Right now, the query is working but the ComboBox isn't being populated.  What am I doing wrong?  Please help, thanks.

HERE'S MY CODE:

```
    Private Sub RetrieveMySQLdata()

    Try
        Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim dbQuery As String = ""
        Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbTable As New DataTable
        If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbConn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database=accounting", FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem, My.Settings.DB_Port, My.Settings.DB_UserID, My.Settings.DB_Password)
            dbConn.Open()
        End If

        dbQuery = "SELECT *" & _
                   "FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber " & _
                   "WHERE customer.accountNumber = '" & TextBoxAccount.Text & "'"
        With dbCmd
            .CommandText = dbQuery
            .Connection = dbConn
        End With
        With dbAdapter
            .SelectCommand = dbCmd
            .Fill(dbtable)
        End With
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To dbTable.Rows.Count - 1
            ComboBoxCard.ValueMember = "ccNumber"

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is using inline-SQL queries.

Comment: Thought you were offering a solution.  But yes, you're right.  I'm doing this because I haven't learned any other way of doing it yet - I'm still learning.

Comment: Since you're still learning, you'll want to read up about "SQL Injection Attacks" and how to prevent/avoid them.  That will give you the knowledge about not using inline-SQL queries.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you trying to populate the `ComboBox`?  The only interaction I see is here:

```
For i = 0 To dbTable.Rows.Count - 1
    ComboBoxCard.ValueMember = "ccNumber"
Next
```

Which I'm guessing isn't doing what you think it's doing.  For one thing, you're setting `ValueMember` to the same value multiple times in a loop.  Nothing in the statement changes with each iteration of the loop, so why loop it?

More specifically, `ValueMember` isn't actually any kind of displayed value.  [It's used to indicate which field in the bound data should contain the value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx).  This is used when you provide a `DataSource` for the control, which you're missing.

I'll assume the `DataSource` should be `dbTable`, so you're probably looking to do something like this:

```
ComboBoxCard.DataSource = dbTable
ComboBoxCard.ValueMember = "ccNumber"
ComboBoxCard.DisplayMember = "Some Other Field in the database"
```

I don't remember if you need to explicitly call `.DataBind()` on the control after these statements, but the example I linked to doesn't do it so I'll leave it out.

Essentially what you're *trying* to do in your code is loop through the results and add them to the `ComboBox`.  You don't need to do this.  The `ComboBox` is capable of doing this internally if you just point its `DataSource` to the set of data being used and tell it which fields it needs to use on that set.  This is called [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: Thanks David, for being kind with your response.  I didn't realize that the ComboBox was capable of handeling the looping through the records by itself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't setting the `DataSource` for the ComboBox object.  Instead of this code:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To dbTable.Rows.Count - 1
    ComboBoxCard.ValueMember = "ccNumber"
Next
```

Use something like this code:

```
ComboBoxCard.DataSource = dbTable
ComboBoxCard.ValueMember = "ccNumber"
ComboBoxCard.DisplayMember = "(some other column if you want)"
```